# "width=device-width" for iPhone but not for iPad

Tags: html, css, iphone, ipad, viewport

On my website I have the following meta tag :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The following HTML :

```
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner clearfix">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the following css :

```
.inner{width:1060px;}
@media screen and (max-width:640px){
    .inner{width:100%;}
}
```

My problem : on Ipad, the width of the page is blocked at 768px while my site is 1060px wide. I would like the website to fit the width of the iPad, but I need to keep a 100% width on iPhone.

Can you help me please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This will cover both portrait and landscape.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .inner { width: auto; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the "mobile css" on iPad! I just want the regular page (identical to the display on a computer), but fitted to the iPad screen.

Comment: Ah. I updated above, if your mobile styles are up to 640px then the above shouldn't affect it.

Comment: I just tried your solution: if I do this, my ".inner" div are 768px wide instead of 1060px wide, so their content is broken. I just need that on iPad, the page still makes 1060px wide but fitted to the screen (for information, it's the default behavior when I don't put meta viewport).